# How to use query modifiers with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't see how to use query modifiers like `$min`/`$max` with mongoose in the docs. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any natural way to do that when using Mongoose, as Mongoose performs a lot of operations on your behalf to make things convenient that may conflict with some of these operations normally.

I've not tried this, but you may be able to do this:

```
Model.find( { $query: { <query> },
    $max: { myField: 100 }, $min: { myField: 10 } }, function(err, models) {
    // do something with results
});
```

When using the `$query` syntax and modifiers, you can't use other things like mongoose's `sort`, etc as they must be specified explicitly in the `$query` definition.

Alternatively, you could use one or more of the query operators such as `$gte`. `$min` and `$max`, as query modifiers, both force MongoDb to use an index where the other operators do not.

```
Model.find().gte("myField", 10).exec(function(err, models) {})
```

As pointed out in comments, you can also use `setOptions` ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions)). However, it still has the same restrictions that you can't use it and many of the other options.

In any case, I'd suggest you should consider using the other query operators such as `$gte`, etc. instead anyway and let the database query engine make a smart choice based on the query and available indexes what makes sense rather than forcing index use through `$max`/`$min.` By using either, even if there's a better choice for an index, they will be used.

Comment: There's a query operator for `$min`/`$max`? I don't see those in the docs. I do see `$gte` though.

Comment: No, there aren't .. they are query modifiers. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/

Comment: It's odd that mongoose has most of the other cursor methods except `$min` and `$max`.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a way. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions states that it supports all the cursor methods that the driver does. I guess the most used methods are defined directly on the Query prototype for easy chaining.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that detail I'd forgotten (the surface area of some of these APIs is LARGE, and that's not a method I'd use normally). Also, added a bit of an opinion about using alternatives anyway.